# Ошибка выполнения при удалении элемента контейнера в цикле

Tags: c++, алгоритм, stl, vector, вектор

Код собирается нормально но при выполнении получаю ошибку доступа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<string> v;

    v.push_back("-");
    v.push_back("+");
    v.push_back("-");

    auto it = v.begin();

    for (it; it != v.end(); it++)
        if (*it == "+"){
            v.erase(it); // сдесь ошибка выполнения
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После удаления элемента итераторы становятся не валидными. Правильно будет  написать следующим образом (я заменил цикл `for` на `while`, так как вы итератор `it` объявили вне цикла, и цикл `while` в этом случае смотрится лучше. Хотя лучше использовать цикл `for` с объявлением итератора внутри цикла)

```
while ( it != v.end() )
    if (*it == "+"){
        it = v.erase(it);
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
```

Общий подход для такой задачи пишется в одну строчку

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//...

v.erase( std::remove( v.begin(), v.end(), "+" ), v.end() );
```

Если хотите удалить только один элемент, то можно записать следующим образом:

```
auto it = std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), "+" );

if ( it != v.end() ) v.erase( it );
```

Comment: в втором примере из вектора удалятся все элементы с плюсом, а мне нужно ужалить только первый встретившийся плюсовой элемент. за первый пример большое вам спасибо я понял в чем ошибка

Comment: @perfect У вас и в первом примере удаляются все элементы с "+", так как вы не завершаете цикл.

Comment: да действительно. спасибо вам